# How to use Javascript map method to access nested objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

When I run the below code and try accessing the "id" within images using the map() method, it gives me undefined. Whereas, accessing the reId/name/dob/number is the same as console.log(d.reId)

```
var data = [
    {
      reId: 'huih23432',
      name: 'skdskdss',
      dob: '26/06/1998',
      number: '34535353543',
      images: {
        "id": 'https://picsum.photos/200',
        "link": 'https://picsum.photos/200',
      },
    },
    {
    "name": "x"
    }


]

data.map((d)=>{
    console.log(d.images.id)
})
```

I want a solution using map() method itself to access the id | link within "images" key.

Comment: you have to add check of  key as in second object there is no image key like d && d.image && d.image.id

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access Javascript nested objects safely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18178406/access-javascript-nested-objects-safely)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var data = [
    {
      reId: 'huih23432',
      name: 'skdskdss',
      dob: '26/06/1998',
      number: '34535353543',
      images: {
        "id": 'https://picsum.photos/201',
        "link": 'https://picsum.photos/200',
      },
    },
    {
    "name": "x"
    }


]

data.map((d)=>{

    if (typeof d.images != 'undefined') 
    console.log(d.images.id);
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to return in the map callback

```
var imageIds = data.map(d=>d.images && d.images.id)
       .filter(id => id); // filter out null elements
```

Comment: @phnka this is working. But I am wondering why nested objects are accessible simply with the dot(.) operator?

Comment: I needed something in this format data.map((d)=>{
    <h1>{d.images.id}</h1>
})

For my React code

Comment: this doesn't really work as it returns an array with the id and undefined.  can you explain this notation:  d=d.images && d.images.id along with .filter(id=>id)