# how do I read values inside the nested map using nodejs or javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

I am very new in javascript and currently trying to read the value `newMap` but don't know, who
do I read the values of Map?

```js
const map1 = new Map();

map1.set('usagesUnkown', 10);
map1.set('usagesUnkown2', 10);

const newMap = new Map();
newMap.set("anoop",map1);
```

I have already try these answer [text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62901570/how-to-use-javascript-map-method-to-access-nested-objects)
but nothing is working.

Comment: use `get()`: `newMap.get('something')`

Comment: Your confusion is because the question you've linked to is regarding the `map()` method of an **Array**, not a `Map` object. For details on the latter, here's an MDN reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map. As @0stone0 points out, you need to use `get()` to retrieve the value from a `Map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

```js
const map1 = new Map();

map1.set('usagesUnkown', 10);
map1.set('usagesUnkown2', 10);

const newMap = new Map();
newMap.set('anoop', map1);

const nestedValue = newMap.get('anoop').get('usagesUnkown');
console.log(nestedValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const map1 = new Map();

map1.set('usagesUnkown', 10);
map1.set('usagesUnkown2', 10);

const newMap = new Map();
newMap.set("anoop",map1);

const refToMap1 = newMap.get("anoop"); //return map 1
const usagesUnkown = refToMap1.get("usagesUnkown"); //return 10

//loop through a map
refToMap1 .forEach((value, key) => {
  console.log(value, key);
});
```