# How to check if a property inside multiple objects exists in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am not a JS developer (using JS inside WKWebView on iOS, and it needs to inject some data onto a page, but that makes no difference for this question, as I'm interested in purely JS aspect of it), hence this is a very basic question, apologies for that.

I have a structure like this:

```
{ "a": 
  { "b": 
    { "c": 
      { "property": "value" }
    }
  }
}
```

Everything from "a" down to "property" is optional, and may not be present. I need to get the value of the "property".

Currently I have this:

```
  function f(value) {

      var json = JSON.parse(value);
      ...
      var prop = json.a.b.c.property;
      ...
```

This seems works, but of course if any part of `a.b.c.property` is missing I am getting an error in log:

> A JavaScript exception occurred: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'json.a.b.c.property')

Instead I want to exit function early if property is not present. So do I need to compare each level to `undefined`, or is there a better way to do it?

```
    var json = JSON.parse(value);
    if json.a == undefined || json.a.b == undefined || json.a.b.c == undefined || json.a.b.c.property == undefined {
        return;
    }
    ...
    var prop = json.a.b.c.property;
    ...
```

Comment: The variable you've named `json` is an object, not JSON. JSON is a text format.

Comment: Basically, yes, that's what you need to do. Sorry.

Comment: See also [Access Javascript nested objects safely](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18178406/215552)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a modern web browser (read: not IE), then you can use the new [`?.` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

```
var prop = json?.a?.b?.c.property;
```